# How to change x-Axes label position in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to change the label position, like padding or margin in CSS?
[image: current chart]

I would like to have the labels above the x-Axes.

Comment: Update: https://jsfiddle.net/ew7chLed/1/ removed the y-axis grid

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `xAxes` label positions with the following steps:

1. Add `.getContext("2d")` to the call that gets the `ctx` canvas object:

   ```
   var ctx = document.getElementById("gescanntePackzettelChart").getContext("2d");
   ```
2. Hide the current xAxes `ticks`:

   ```
   xAxes: [{
       ticks: {
           display: false
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add an `animation` to the `options` config, and use the canvas [`fillText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) method to create new labels:

   ```
   animation: {
       duration: 1,
       onComplete: function() {
           var controller = this.chart.controller;
           var chart = controller.chart;
           var xAxis = controller.scales['x-axis-0'];

           var numTicks = xAxis.ticks.length;        
           var xOffsetStart = xAxis.width / numTicks;
           var halfBarWidth = (xAxis.width / (numTicks * 2));

           xAxis.ticks.forEach(function(value, index) {
               var xOffset = (xOffsetStart * index) + halfBarWidth;
               var yOffset = chart.height - 20;
               ctx.fillText(value, xOffset, yOffset);
           });

       }
   }
   ```

   For `xOffset`, to figure out the correct position, take the `xAxis` width and divide it by the number of tick labels. This will tell you how wide each bar is. Then, multiply that number by the current `index` to position the label in front of the correct bar. Finally, add add the width of half a bar to center the labels in the bar.

   For the `yOffset`, start with the chart's height and subtract however much you want to move the labels up.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5tnkr4n/124

Comment: The parameters of fillText is `fillText(value, x, y)`.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco While the correct values were being used, it seems like I completely confused the x and y labels when I wrote this answer. Good catch! I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Tot-Zam's response, it's possible to use the ChartJs scale object's methods to define the context pixel coordinates easier. You also don't need to define a `ctx` object - it is already accessible using the `this.chart` object.

```
    animation: {
          duration: 0,
          onComplete: function() {
            let chart = this.chart;
            let controller = chart.controller; 
            let axis = controller.scales['x-axis-0'];
            let yOffset = chart.height - 5;
            axis.ticks.forEach(function(value, index) {
              let xOffset = axis.getPixelForValue(value);     
              chart.ctx.fillText(value, xOffset, yOffset);
            })
          }
        }
```

Working repl: https://repl.it/@lunarplasma/ChartJs-custom-axis-labels